# Running "node <app name>" does not do anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, botframework

I have a bot app called "vgen.js". Whenever I run "node vgen", the prompt/directory disappears, and the blinker is just sitting there at the far left of the screen.

I have been following directions from this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzRWCZlclrY&list=PLDcL8dhuVQJwF6pY8BwAlt6MCUUwyLoLi&index=2

I have tried reinstalling everything (I deleted all of the files except vgen.js). I ran the following:

```
npm init (I set it up)
npm install -g node-modules
npm install --save botbuilder
```

After running those commands, I still get the same results.

Here is vgen.js:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
var  bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

bot.dialog('/', [

    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
    },

    function(session, results) {
        session.send('Hello %s', results.response);
    }

]);
```

When I type something and press enter, nothing happens. I expect my bot to respond to my inputs and at least ask me my name. I decided to ctrl+c out of it, and noticed that the whole time I was entering commands into CMD... but it only showed those echos AFTER I cancelled out of the node app.

Comment: What if you run `node vgen.js`?

Comment: So, a few things here... I see from Michael's answer that it looks like you might be using not only V3 of Bot Framework, but an OLD version of v3. I can't remember where it is in the docs, but I'm fairly sure that MS is advocating that if you want to use v3, that you use at least v3.15.

Comment: Second, it seems like you're just starting your bot project--are you *certain* that you want to use V3? There's a [deprecation notice to end support for BF V3](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3) by 12/31/19. I would advise that if you're just getting started, then to use the updated V4 version of BF. And here's a link to the [console-echo bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/01.console-echo) in the repo of samples

Comment: If I run `npm install --save botbuilder`, will I get the latest version? Isn't that the best?

Comment: Okay, so I reinstalled everything _again_ and doing `node vgen` just instantly terminates and does nothing. It's strange because it doesn't seem as if the program is running in command prompt, as if it were just a command (It doesn't seem to be accepting any keyboard input). What I did differently is while installing it, I didn't include the "-g" argument when I was installing the node-modules.
Before I did `npm install -g node-modules`,

and this time I did `npm install node-modules`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this doesn't work with the latest version of botbuilder (the one installed by npm install --save botbuilder).

Try adding this to your package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "botbuilder": "3.13.1"
  }
```

Then run "npm install"

Try "node vgen" again

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it is still doing the exact same thing